# mulFromInteger was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

i have strange errors got from my flutter pages do some math computation with null value. or i assume it was makes errors happening.

in my case i do computation such as (120 * null) inside stateful widget init section. when i build in release mode. I have debug view which means it read background in my apps and shows:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method '_mulFromInteger' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried Calling:_mulFromInteger(134)
```

is multiply operations (*) have method  behind of it? or can anyone explain what is _mulFromInteger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This implementation of `int` in dart is provided by the class [_IntegerImplementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/cbd17b535f3d3274188c4ce13a55b1178211a7ec/runtime/lib/integers.dart). In this class you can see:

```
num operator *(num other) => other._mulFromInteger(this);
```

You can see that the implementation of the operator `*` calls `_mulFromInteger` on the argument. That's why you get this error.

Comment: thanks now it's clear for method. one more for why release mode still show error debug?

Comment: I get this error when using Timer. I gave null in Duration and this happened.