# sign in The method '_mulFromInteger' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

I've got sign in methode in my provider.

```
  Future<void> signIn(
      String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final clientID = "com.super.app";
    final body = "username=$email&password=$password&grant_type=password";
    final String clientCredentials =
        const Base64Encoder().convert("$clientID:".codeUnits);

    try {
      final http.Response response =
          await http.post("http://localhost:8888/auth",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": "Basic $clientCredentials"
              },
              body: body);
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
//      if (jsonResponse["error"] != null) {
//        throw HttpException(jsonResponse["error"]);
//      }
      _userId = 1;
      _token = jsonResponse['access_token'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: jsonResponse['expires_in'],
        ),
      );
      _autoLogout();
      notifyListeners();
      final userData = json.encode(
        {
          'userId': 1,
          'email': email,
          'token': _token,
          'expiryDate': _expiryDate.toIso8601String(),
        },
      );
      sharedPreferences.setString('userData', userData);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString()); //<-- misleading error
    }
  }
```

All works fine but when incorrect login credential are passed then I get misleading error

```
flutter: NoSuchMethodError: The method '_mulFromInteger' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: _mulFromInteger(1000000)
```

The back end passing error code 400 and body {"error": "invalid client"} but I get that strange error as output. So what does that error means and why do I get that instead of body

Comment: can you provide more details, where is the error happening, in the `try` or `catch` block?

Comment: @LoVe it is in the catch block... commented in the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549620/mulfrominteger-was-called-on-null may help clarify where the problem is coming from, also, try `print(error)` just to see if it can print something without giving an error

Comment: @LoVe That link doesn't really help in this situation and `print(error)` prints the same error

Comment: I would try to pear down the code until you isolate exactly where the error it getting thrown. Removing try/catch might help with that. I think the link that LoVe provided might actually be on the right track. There is a comment there about a null Duration causing such an error and you also have a Duration. Additionally, check the response status code before you try to do something with the response body. If the status code is 400 then there is no use trying to extract a non-existent access token.

Comment: Side note: client apps probably don't need to worry about the `userId`. Let the server worry about that. The client only needs to worry about the email, password, and access token.

Comment: @Suragch I've seen that comment and absolutely forgot about the Duration in my code.. Yes that might be the case of the issue. However I thought that try block will skip everything once response from http throw an error

Comment: `http` doesn't throw an error just because the server returns a 400 or 500 code.

Comment: @Suragch I see... to be honest I tried also to fix it as you can see in updated code (commented) but I get an error `Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null` So basically I can get rid of the try-catch block and simply use if else statement.. if response has error in the body throw error else continue

Comment: I think what you meant to write is this: `jsonResponse["error"] != null`. I would still check `response.statusCode` rather than testing for null, though.

Comment: @Suragch You're right. I just noticed that silly mistake ...All fixed and working as it should

Comment: Great. Consider adding your own answer below so that others who come here can benefit.

Comment: @Suragch Please you do it so I can at least give you some points for your help

Comment: @delmin, I don't need the points. :) Besides, I prefer to answer questions with a single topic. This has two or three different issues.

Comment: @Suragch you're right.. I'll do it then... Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from @Suragch comments I had few problem in my code. First I thought that when server return 400 code then it will automatically throw an error and skip rest of the lines.. I was wrong so basically I had to uncomment my code for http exceptions and in my button catch the error

```
  try {
    await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signIn(
        emailController.text, passwordController.text);
  } on HttpException catch (error) {
    print(error.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
```